# sed pattern match date

Tags: regex, sed

I'm struggling to understand how to use pattern matching using sed.

Within a large file, I want to replace the following date format from `dd.mm.yyyy` to the `dd/mm/yyyy` so basically replace the dots with slashes. The file contains multiple occurrences of dates in the stated format, however, it must not change full stops at the end of sentences etc.

```
sed 's/\./\//g' <file_name>
```

does the job but changes every (.) so I need some way of performing a pattern match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\/\2\/\3/g' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                  # substitute
  \([0-9][0-9]\)    # group 1, 2 digits
  \.                # a dot
  \([0-9][0-9]\)    # group 2, 2 digits
  \.                # a dot
  \([0-9]\{4\}\)    # group 3, 4 digits
/
  \1                # content of group 1
  \/                # a slash
  \2                # content of group 2
  \/                # a slash
  \3                # content of group 3
/g                  # global flag
```

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly and the explanation is great!

Comment: May I suggest `sed -r 's|([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})|\1/\2/\3|g'` or `perl -pe 's|(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})|\1/\2/\3|g'` or `perl -pe 's|\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|$&=~s#\.#/#rg|e'`.